# Angular with Rails - submit not working with Angular controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on Rails cast #405, and I'm attempting to learn how to integrate Rails with Angular--I'm a newbie on this integration.

In `assets/javascripts/raffle.js.coffee`, I have:

```
app = angular.module 'Raffle', []

app.controller "RaffelCtrl", @RaffelCtrl = ($scope) ->
  $scope.entries = [
    {name: "Larry"}
    {name: "Curly"}
    {name: "Moe"}
  ]

  $scope.addEntry = ->
    $scope.entries.push($scope.newEntry)
    $scope.newEntry = {}
```

In my `show` template (`haml`), I have...

```
%div{ 'ng-app' => 'Raffle'}
  %div{ 'ng-controller' => 'RaffelCtrl'}
    %form{"ng-submit" => "addEntry"}
      %input{"ng-model" => "newEntry.name", :type => "text"}/
      %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Add"}/
    %br
    %ul
      %li{"ng-repeat" => "entry in entries"}
        {{entry.name}}
```

When I click on the input button to add another `entry`, nothing happens.  I definitely have contact between the rails view the Angular controller, b/c am able to display the list of entries.  I just can't submit a new one.  Any help would be much appreciated on this.  My gem file has `angularjs-rails` and I'm using Twitter bootstrap.  With my `application.js`, I've removed `turbolinks`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `addEntry` function on your ng-submit like so: `addEntry()`, then it should work.